# How to improve the loops in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to create a code for my company where it reads 70 files from the web and a lot of data from the files. But in the simulator it is taking 10 minutes to the execution. I believe this time is very high. So, I ask you, experienced guys, if you see one way to improve the code and let it faster. Below, there is a sketch of my code. Thank you.

```
for (int i=0; i<stockList.count;i++){
            stringToURL = [NSString [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.mycompany.com/File%d",i]];
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringToURL];
            NSError *error = nil;
            content = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
            sum1 = 0.00;
            sum2 = 0.00;
            for (j=1; j<=90; j++) {
                sum1 = sum1 + [[[content objectAtIndex:30*j+10] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."] floatValue];
            }
            for (j=1; j<=200; j++) {
                sum2 = sum2 + [[[content objectAtIndex:33*j+10] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."] floatValue];
            }
            if ((sum2+sum1)/2 > target) [saveFile addObject:[NSString initWithformat:@"File%d,i]];
            NSLog(@"%d",i);
        }
```

Comment: Run the code through the profiler and see where the actual problem lies. Certainly doing 70 synchronous Internet file transfers is going to be the vast majority of the problem.

Comment: don't you have a way to have your processing being executed previously on a server instead of doing the work on the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is going to be dead slow no matter what you do, but that particular code will be brutally slow because of the repeated parsing and string substitutions.   I'd bet you'll probably see spikes in memory usage, too, due to autorelease traffic..  That is the nature of scraping text and trying to treat it as data.

At the least, the data should be published in a machine readable form.  Perhaps as JSON encoded data or as plists?

Ideally, given the data volume, there would be a web server that would provide an HTTP API that your app could connect to and grab data.   Better yet, the API could provide a "bulk load from scratch" and "give me any deltas since XXXX" type end points that would allow you to both initialize a new app and enable your app to cache data, only applying updates to changed data.

Comment: Thank you. All information will be useful to review the strategy of the company.

Comment: @George It is a pretty high level assessment.  Without knowing more, it is hard to dive deeper.   But it really does sound like you need a client/server architecture.  Note that if you have more than one client and need to actually coordinate/merge changes from them, then you *definitely* need a server that can do the heavy lifting (or something bleeding edge).